# English translation for Kovetz Maamarim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, translation

I’m looking for an English translation of Rabbi Elchanan Washerman’s sefer, “Kovetz Maamarim”. Are there any publications?

Comment: I've never seen one, FWIW.